# How to prevent JQuery Dialog queue buildup in hover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

When I use `jQuery UI Dialog` in hover event, I have following problem: after moving mouse up and down the list of items, the event is being fired even after I stop moving mouse, until it blinks the number of times I hovered over those items.

https://jsfiddle.net/fump59sm/

I would like it to behave the way that when I move a mouse away, it stops, the last one being the one with the content of the item I have just moved away from.

I have found that it behaves this way, when I change `close` to `destroy`:

https://jsfiddle.net/fump59sm/1/

But destroy just wipes it off abruptly, without this nice `fade` effect.

Also when I use:

```
close: function(){
    $(this).dialog('destroy');
}
```

doesn't solve the problem, since it doesn't have time to disappear before I enter another item and dissappears on every second item:

https://jsfiddle.net/fump59sm/3/

I also tried to use `.stop(true)`, but to no avail.

Is there a better way to achieve this (get rid of the queue build up) without losing the animation effect? Or at least is there a way to add animation to `destroy`?

Comment: add a timer, check to see if it's already playing the animation, and if so, don't do it.